# Web api always resolves to /

Tags: go

I have a simple Go App that is pulling information from Jira and returning it as a JSON blob. In development, everything works. In production every url resolves to "/". I am running behind IIS using a web.config that looks like a .NET Core app.  I'll paste the relevant pieces but need to leave some modules out to protect proprietary information.

EDIT

It is worth noting I have one site with multiple applications in IIS, so the url is something like `<COMPUTER_NAME>/jira-report/velocity`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "example.com/jira/internal/api"
)

// entry point for application
func main() {
    handleRequests()
}

// map the api endpoints to urls and handle them
func handleRequests() {
    http.HandleFunc("/velocity", api.Velocity)
    http.HandleFunc("/", api.Home)

    port := "5000"
    if os.Getenv("ASPNETCORE_PORT") != "" {
        port = os.Getenv("ASPNETCORE_PORT")
        fmt.Println(port)
    }

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))
}
```

```
package api

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "example.com/jira/internal/board"
    "example.com/jira/internal/config"
    "example.com/jira/internal/velocity"
    "github.com/tkanos/gonfig"
)

var configuration config.Config = config.Config{}

type RouteInfo struct {
    Description string
    Name string
    Url string
}

func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var velocity RouteInfo = RouteInfo{"Display velocity statistics for boards we are interested in.", "Velocity", "/velocity"}
    var routes []RouteInfo = []RouteInfo{}

    routes = append(routes, velocity)
    js, err := json.Marshal(routes)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(js)
}

func Velocity(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("INFO - Route Velocity")
    var results map[string]velocity.Statistics = map[string]velocity.Statistics{}

    // get all the boards
    var boards board.Boards = board.GetBoards(configuration.Teams)

    // get sprint info by board ID
    var count int = len(boards.Values)
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        var board board.Board = boards.Values[i]

        // get the velocityChart for the board
        var chart velocity.VelocityChart = velocity.GetVelocityChart(board.Id)
        var stats velocity.Statistics = velocity.GetStatistics(chart)
        results[board.Name] = stats
    }

    js, err := json.Marshal(results)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(js)
}

// setup the global configuration
func init() {
    err := gonfig.GetConf("./config.development.json", &configuration)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to get configuration: %v", err))
    }

    f, err := os.OpenFile("./logs/log.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0664)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening file: %v", err)
    }

    log.SetOutput(f)
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Sites\JiraReport\jira.exe" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go was receiving the sub application as part of the url, so I modified my handles to account for this.  If there's a better solution please provide it, but this at least works.

```
func getUrlPrefix() string {
    var prefix string = "/"
    var subUrl string = os.Getenv("URL_PREFIX")

    if (subUrl != ""){
        prefix = prefix + subUrl + "/"
    }

    return  prefix
}

func handleRequests() {
    var prefix string = getUrlPrefix()
    var port string = getPort()

    log.Printf("INFO - Serving requests at %v on port %v\n", prefix, port)
    http.HandleFunc(fmt.Sprintf("%vvelocity", prefix), api.Velocity)
    http.HandleFunc(prefix , api.Home)


    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))
}
```